# Content/Child Pages in Directory/Folder does not work with Master Page in Root Directory in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website in VS 2012. I have a Master Page having Bootstrap Menu in root directory and some child/content pages , here all child pages work fine with master page i-e drop down menu works.

Now problem comes here, when i create a folder/directory and add a page inside that folder and also inherit Master Page, here Master page menu shows but drop down menu does not work.

Kindly help me in such regards.

Comment: What drop down menu? What is it showing? Or do you mean the bootstrap menu? And what is not working? Populating? Navigating? What is the error message? Please add more details otherwise it might hard for you  to receive some help.

Comment: yes bootstrap horizontal menu is not populating only in child/content pages in subdirectory

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer did u even read the question? it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found that the easiest approach to ensuring that your scripts are targeted at the appropriate locations is to use the ResolveUrl() method which will return the absolute URL based on a relative position :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/efsm-common.js") %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `ResolveUrl()` in src

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js") %>"></script>
```